# ASSIGN win XP commandline output to variable

Tags: windows, linux, shell, awk, translation

i would like to translate a following script from linux shell to Windows XP shell

```
GPSID=$(awk '/GPSID/ {print $3}' gora.RTK ) 
awk -v variable=${GPSID} 'BEGIN {printf "Numer seryjny : " variable,$1}' >>out.txt
```

The second line has been translated; the problem is with defining a variable that contains shell output in windows :-(

Comment: Please, tag your requests correctly

Comment: Are you really stuck with DOS (XP Shell)? It is severely limited compared to a linux shell. If possible I would highly recommend going with one of the script languages available in XP (VBScript or jscript) if possible. Or even better yet if possible install powershell. You could also install cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

ok problem fixed

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('awk "/GPSID/ {print $3}" gora.RTK ') do set var=%%a
awk "BEGIN {printf \"GPSID : \" }" >out.txt
echo %var% >>out.txt
```

This code basicly does what I wanted to do.

You are great  Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to recurse through the output of the command, you can use `for /f`. Something like:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%L in (`awk '/GPSID/ {print $3}' gora.RTK`) do (
    awk 'BEGIN {printf "Numer seryjny : " %%L,$1}' >> out.txt
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not awk proficient, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo Hello World') do set var=%%a

NOTE: use %a instead of %%a when trying on the command line else keep it as %%a if using in a batch file.

Where 'echo Hello World' is the command whose output you want to capture and "var" is the name of the variable where the output will be stored.

Comment: That is as close as you will be able to come, but the OP should be aware that multiline strings cannot be stored in a DOS var.