# Batch file assign returned values from a command into a variable (from powershell)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

i am refering to this question
[ASSIGN win XP commandline output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537404)

i am trying to use it on a powershell code segment
so i typed

```
powershell date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -format yyyyMMdd
```

and confirm it returns like

```
20100601
```

but then if i tried to

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('powershell date get-date -format yyyyMMdd
') do set var=%a
```

then it failed to work as expected. how can i transfer the date to a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('powershell "get-date; get-date -format yyyyMMdd"') do set var=%a
```

is what you wanted.

Comment: exactly! i hope i knew the way to quote it inside there.