# Store powershell output in a variable in CMD

Tags: powershell, windows-7, batch-file, cmd

In a batchfile, how do I store the output of a powershell command in a variable
This isn't working

```
set yest=powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%Y%m%d"


powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%Y%m%d"
```

gives `20130623`

```
set yest=powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%Y%m%d"
echo %yest%
```

gives `powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "md"`

Comment: Are you using echo in powershell or are those two different scripts / consoles?

Comment: echo is in a batch file.. I'm using powershell in a batch file

Comment: Actually, looks like this was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955512/batch-file-assign-returned-values-from-a-command-into-a-variable-from-powershel

Comment: @AthomSfere It works from command line. But when I put it in a batch file, it gives me an error `a was unexpected at this time`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closing braces and percent need to be escaped/doubled.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell get-date((get-date^).addDays(-1^)^) -uformat "%%Y%%m%%d"') do set d8=%%a
echo %d8%
pause
```

Comment: @Jubjub Bandersnatch No, that's not true - it doesn't use backticks and works as posted.

Comment: Right you are. I just assumed those were backticks because I always use them.

Comment: whats with the for /f?