# Find the version of a installed program from batch file

Tags: batch-file, wmic

We have a batch file that installs several programs as part of the developers setup. This is ran periodically when we get new versions of used components. So it would be nice only to install if the versions are different.

At the command prompt I can run this and get back the version installed:

```
wmic datafile where name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Company\\Product\\Version12\\Product.exe' get version /format:list
```

Which gives the output `Version=12.1.369.0`.

However when I put this into a batch file like this and try to extract the version:

```
echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('"wmic datafile where^(name^="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Company\\Product\\Version12\\Product.exe" get version /format:list"') DO (SET "RESULT=%%I")
ECHO %RESULT%
```

I get the response `\\Common was unexpected at this time.`

Some parts may be redundant as I've been trying stuff off the 'Net to correct this.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a set of misplaced double quotes, as well as an extra `(`.

WMIC uses SQL syntax, and strings are enclosed in single quotes.The internal single quotes do not interfere with the command enclosing single quotes.

You can put double quotes around the WHERE clause (not including the WHERE keyword) to avoid some escape issues within the FOR DO() clause.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Company\\Product\\Version12\\Product.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO SET "RESULT=%%I"
ECHO %RESULT%
```

But this may not quite be the whole solution. You can't see it with the above code, but RESULT actually contains a trailing carriage return (0x0D). This is due to a quirk with how FOR /F handles WMIC unicode output. Every line of WMIC output will have the extra trailing carriage return.

As long as you always access RESULT using `%RESULT%` (normal expansion), then you will not have any problems. But if you should ever need delayed expansion, then you can have problems, as demonstrated below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Company\\Product\\Version12\\Product.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO SET "RESULT=%%I"
ECHO %RESULT%xxx
ECHO !RESULT!xxx
```

One convenient method to strip the unwanted carriage return is to use an extra level of FOR.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Company\\Product\\Version12\\Product.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "RESULT=%%A"
ECHO %RESULT%xxx
ECHO !RESULT!xxx
```

Comment: I now get `Node - COMP009811\nERROR:\nDescription - Invalid query\nxxx\nxxx` (you can't get line breaks in comments)

Comment: The first quote is in the wrong place - I am guessing it should be after the equality symbol.  Now I get `- Invalid alias verb.`

Comment: @graham.reeds - Sorry, all fixed. I had tested successfully with an actual program, but when I copied in your sample fictitious program, I accidentally overwrote the critical single quotes. The double quotes are exactly where they need to be.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the subroutine I use for this in my own software update batch script:

```
:getfattr
set %1=
setlocal
set "name=%~f2"
set "name=%name:\=\\%"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic datafile where "name='%name:'=\'%'" get %1 /format:list') do @^
for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do endlocal & set "%%B" & goto :eof
echo>&2 getfattr failed
endlocal
goto :eof
```

It can get any file attribute supported by `wmic datafile get`. For example, here's how you might get the file version for the currently installed Adobe Reader:

```
call :getfattr version "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
echo "!version!"
```

After doing that, environment variable `version` will contain the requested version string. If `:getfattr` fails, `version` is guaranteed to be unset.

A test execution trace for that example looks like this (delayed expansion was already enabled, though this is not assumed by :getfattr):

```
>call :getfattr version "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

>set version=

>setlocal

>set "name=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

>set "name=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 11.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe"

>for /F "delims=" %A in ('wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 11.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe'" get version /format:list') do @for /F "delims=" %B in ("%A") do endlocal   & set "%B"   & goto :eof

>endlocal   & set "Version=11.0.18.21"   & goto :eof

>echo "!version!"
"11.0.18.21"
```

As you can see, it's pretty direct and doesn't faff about too much. It does, however, tiptoe through a minefield of `cmd` and `wmic` gotchas.

First, the name of the attribute you want to get is also the name used for the variable you want the result to end up in (`version` in the test above). Inside the subroutine, that name is `%1`, so `set %1=` clears it.

The filename you pass in needs a bit of preprocessing before it can be safely handed to `wmic` and a shell variable is required for that, so `setlocal` is issued to avoid stomping the caller's variables.

`set "name=%~f2"` copies the name to an environment variable after stripping off any surrounding double-quotes and expanding it to a full pathname. Double quotes surround the entire `set` argument to prevent grief caused by ampersands or parentheses in pathnames.

`wmic` queries use a SQL-like syntax, where string values are surrounded by single quote `'` characters and `\` is an escape that suppresses any special meaning of the following character. Since both of these are legal in Windows pathnames, all occurrences of either need a `\` prefix. `set "name=%name:\=\\%"` escapes embedded backslashes, and the `'%name:'=\'%'` construct in the `wmic` command line escapes embedded single quotes and adds the required surrounding ones.

`cmd`'s parser doesn't turn off special processing between single quotes, and the name no longer has any surrounding double quotes, so embedded spaces, parentheses or ampersands could potentially break things. To guard against that, `wmic`'s entire `name=` argument gets double quoted. There's no need for special handling for double quotes already inside the name, because double quotes *are* prohibited in Windows filenames so there can't be any.

The `for` command line containing the `wmic` command ends with a `@^` sequence. The `^` serves to attach the next line as the payload of the outer `for` command; the `@` prevents that payload being echoed in an execution trace even if ECHO is on.

That echo suppression is done mainly because the inner `for` exists only to get rid of the spurious CR characters injected by `cmd`'s buggy conversion of `wmic`'s output from Unicode to ASCII (the same technique used in @dbenham's answer) and if it's allowed to echo, those CRs just filthy up the trace with confusing overwrites. As a side benefit, the inner `for` won't execute its own payload when the line it's handed from the outer `for` contains *only* a CR, a version-dependent number of which `wmic` insists on emitting. The inner `for`'s payload *does* get echoed if ECHO is on, so tracing still captures all the useful happenings.

That payload consists of three &-separated commands, which `for` will expand as a single command line before `cmd` gets to process the individual commands. In particular, this means that `set "%%B"` gets expanded before `endlocal` runs, which puts the variable created by that `set` outside the `setlocal`/`endlocal` scope and makes it available to the caller.

`%%B` will always expand in the format *name=value* because of the `/format:list` switch passed to `wmic`; the name will be the same as that specified with the `get` verb, and this is how the name you pass in ends up choosing the variable you get back. The entire *name=value* argument to `set` is quoted in case the requested attribute contains shell-special characters. This makes :getfattr itself safe, but you might want to use !delayed! expansion rather than %premature% expansion wherever you actually use the variable it hands back to you.

The `& goto :eof` on that same line breaks from both `for` loops and returns to :getfattr's caller as soon as the inner one actually does anything, just in case you pass in some weird name and `wmic get` produces more than one non-blank line of output.

The last three lines only ever run if `wmic` produces no output at all, which is what happens when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

and two ways without external tools
1.**WMIC**

```
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="C:\\install.exe" get Version /format:Textvaluelist
```

Pay attention to the double slashes of file name.

Ready to use script/subroutine:

```
@echo off
:wmicVersion pathToBinary [variableToSaveTo]
setlocal
set "item=%~1"
set "item=%item:\=\\%"


for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='%item%' get Version /format:Textvaluelist"`) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)

if "%~2" neq "" (
    endlocal & (
        echo %version%
        set %~2=%version%
    )
) else (
    echo %version%
)
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Example (it needs a full file path):

```
call wmicVersion.bat "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" cmdver
echo %cmdver%
```

2.**MAKECAB**
as the WMIC is not installed on home versions of windows here's a way with makecab that will run on every windows machine:

```
; @echo off
;;goto :end_help
;;setlocal DsiableDelayedExpansion
;;;
;;;
;;; fileinf /l list of full file paths separated with ;
;;; fileinf /f text file with a list of files to be processed ( one on each line )
;;; fileinf /? prints the help
;;;
;;:end_help
 
; REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
; set NLM=^
 
 
; set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
; if "%~1" equ "/?" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; if "%~2" equ "" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
; if "%~1" equ "/l" (
;  set "_files=%~2"
;  echo !_files:;=%NL%!>"%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  set _process_file="%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  goto :get_info
; )
 
; if "%~1" equ "/f" if exist "%~2" (
;  set _process_file="%~2"
;  goto :get_info
; )
 
; echo incorect parameters & exit /b 1
; :get_info
; set "file_info="
 
; makecab /d InfFileName=%TEMP%\file.inf /d "DiskDirectory1=%TEMP%" /f "%~f0"  /f %_process_file% /v0>nul
 
; for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%f in ("%TEMP%\file.inf") do (
;  set "file_info=%%f"
;  echo !file_info:,=%nl%!
; )
 
; endlocal
;endlocal
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.inf 2>nul
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.path 2>nul
; exit /b 0
 
.set DoNotCopyFiles=on
.set DestinationDir=;
.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFooter=;
.set InfHeader=;
.Set ChecksumWidth=8
.Set InfDiskLineFormat=;
.Set Cabinet=off
.Set Compress=off
.Set GenerateInf=ON
.Set InfDiskHeader=;
.Set InfFileHeader=;
.set InfCabinetHeader=;
.Set InfFileLineFormat=",file:*file*,date:*date*,size:*size*,csum:*csum*,time:*time*,vern:*ver*,vers:*vers*,lang:*lang*"
```

example output (it has a string version which is a small addition to wmic method :) ):

```
c:> fileinfo.bat /l C:\install.exe
    file:install.exe
    date:11/07/07
    size:562688
    csum:380ef239
    time:07:03:18a
    vern:9.0.21022.8
    vers:9.0.21022.8 built by: RTM
    lang:1033
```

**3** Using ***shell.application*** and hybrid batch\jscript.Here's **tooptipInfo.bat** :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off
    
    rem :: the first argument is the script name as it will be used for proper help message
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%
    
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */
 
////// 
FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
if (ARGS.Length < 1 ) {
 WScript.Echo("No file passed");
 WScript.Quit(1);
}
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);
var objShell=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
/////


//fso
ExistsItem = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.FolderExists(path)||FSOObj.FileExists(path);
}

getFullPath = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.GetAbsolutePathName(path);
}
//

//paths
getParent = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    var result="";
    for (var s=0;s<splitted.length-1;s++){
        if (s==0) {
            result=splitted[s];
        } else {
            result=result+"\\"+splitted[s];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


getName = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    return splitted[splitted.length-1];
}
//

function main(){
    if (!ExistsItem(filename)) {
        WScript.Echo(filename + " does not exist");
        WScript.Quit(2);
    }
    var fullFilename=getFullPath(filename);
    var namespace=getParent(fullFilename);
    var name=getName(fullFilename);
    var objFolder=objShell.NameSpace(namespace);
    var objItem=objFolder.ParseName(name);
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx
    WScript.Echo(fullFilename + " : ");
    WScript.Echo(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem,-1));
    
}

main();
```

used against cmd.exe :

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe :
File description: Windows Command Processor
Company: Microsoft Corporation
File version: 6.3.9600.16384
Date created: ?22-?Aug-?13 ??13:03
Size: 347 KB
```

Comment: should include a file example with more than one leaf so it is clear what the path should look like (e.g. c:\\path\\to\\some\\file.exe)

Answer (score 0):

This is my filever bat file.

```
@echo off

If "%~1"=="" goto help
If "%~1"=="/?" goto help
If /i "%~1"=="/h" goto help
If "%~1"=="-?" goto help
If /i "%~1"=="-h" goto help

set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"
echo %errorlevel%
goto finish

:help
Echo.
Echo. FileVer
Echo. -------
Echo.
Echo. Purpose:
Echo.
Echo.    Reports the version number for an exe, dll, and similar files.
Echo.
Echo. Usage:
Echo.
Echo.    filever ^<executable file^>
Echo.
Echo.    filever [/h ^| -h ^| /? ^| -?]    Starts this help
Echo.
echo. Examples:
Echo.
Echo.    filever c:\windows\explorer.exe
Echo.    filever "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
Echo.    filever shell32.dll

Echo.
Echo.    For Help
Echo.
Echo.    filever 

Echo.    filever /?
Echo.

:finish
rem Pause if command double clicked
If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause
```

You seem to have an extra set of quotes around the whole command

One problem with for loops is it wmic outpus a blank line after the version.

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
for /f  "tokens=1 eol= " %%A in ('wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version^|findstr /i /v /c:"version"') do set a=%%A & echo %%A
```

Put it in a file. Although the file has two blank lines.

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version">test.txt
```

Maybe this could work

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
for /f  "tokens=1 eol= " %%A in ('wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version^|findstr /i /v /c:"version"') do if not ""==%%A set a=%%A & echo %%A
```

Or call another batch file and don't return.

Here's a way to getrid of blank lines.

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
for /f  "tokens=1 eol= " %%A in ('wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version^|findstr /i /v /c:"version"^|findstr /i /v /r "^$"') do set a=%%A & echo %A%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"|findstr /i /v /r "^$">test.txt
```

Comment: That's nice but doesn't give me the version in a variable which I can use in batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method, bypasses WMIC for powershell Get-WmiObject.

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b powershell.exe -command "Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_DataFile -Filter \"Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Knuckle.dll'\" | Select-Object Version"
PAUSE
```

Returns this result when double clicking a .cmd batch file.

```
Version
-------
0.0.0.0
```

Comment: you can figure out how to get it into a variable by reading this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955512/batch-file-assign-returned-values-from-a-command-into-a-variable-from-powershel